# Elementary problems with a Loop in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I am working with for-loops in R;

I have a data frame which contains n columns.

I have to build a vector of length n where each element is 1 if the column is a double, 0 otherwise.

this is what I have tried:

```
y<-rep(0,dim.data.frame(datafr)[2])
attach(datafr)
x<-names(dat)
for (j in 1:length(x)){
  for(i in x){
    if(is.double(i)){
      y[j]<-1
    }else{
      y[j]<-0
    }
  }
}
```

However, it does not work since the y vector returned has no 1, but just n 0.

Comment: `sapply(datafr, is.double)` will give you a vector, matching per column. In R `data.frame`s, a column is generally a single class (`numeric`, `integer`, `character`), so there's no need to check more than one value per column.

Answer (score 0):

1. A column in a `data.frame` should all be the same class, so you only need to check past the first value in a column.
2. A simple approach is to create the vector with `sapply` which loops (in this case) over the columns of a frame.

   ```r
   datafr <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=1:5 + 0, d=letters[1:5])
   sapply(datafr, is.double)
   #     a     b     d 
   # FALSE  TRUE FALSE
   ```
3. If you must use a `for` loop, this can be unrolled with

   ```r
   y <- integer(ncol(datafr)) # defaults to 0
   y
   # [1] 0 0 0
   for (j in seq_along(datafr)) {
     if (is.double(datafr[[j]])) {
       y[j] <- 1L
     }
   }
   y
   # [1] 0 1 0
   ```